# Problem filing micro entity status

Tags: uspto, micro-entity

My son and I invented something together. We qualify as micro entity and filed the appropriate form MES.GIB. However PTO came back saying it doesn't correctly identify the application to which it relates.

I filed two forms, one with my name and signature at the top and bottom, and one with his and checked the checkbox at the bottom for both. However, the top says "First Named Inventor". I can put his name on both forms (since he is first) however, it isn't clear on this form where to put my name.

There seems to be no guidance anywhere on how to do this. Can someone who has done it clarify for me?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you include the application number? Also, would you be able to provide the actual text from the USPTO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The USPTO has recently refocused efforts on helping independent inventors through the patenting process.  I would suggest that you contact the PTO's Inventor's Assistance Center (IAC).

Toll-Free: 800-786-9199 or Web: 
https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/support-centers/inventors-assistance-center-iac

Answer (score 0):

You need to include one more form with additional inventor (i.e. You). Please refer to statement checked at the bottom.

> The required additional certification form(s) signed by the other
>   joint inventor(s) are included with this form.

[image]

Comment: I actually did that. The confusion is that on the second inventor's form the first inventor's name goes at the top and the second inventor's name and signature go at the bottom. The form is not at all clear on that. But the PTO cleared it up on a phone call.